# How to resize a Data Grid View Column size

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview

i want to resize c# data grid view column to a custom size. how i can do this?

Comment:  ** 1. Set the AutoSizeColumnsMode property to Fill **.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [DataGridViewColumn.Width Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width.aspx).

You can do this either in the Visual Studio Designer or through code:

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
column.Width = 60;
```

You should be aware that the [DataGridViewColumn.AutoSizeMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode.aspx) setting can affect a column's width too.